# Powershell: List with ADusers - need groups the users are memberof

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users (their CN), and I want a list of the groups they are member of.
I already have a code which almost does the trick, but it shows as follows:

> User1 - group1;group2
>
> User2 - group1;group2;group3 etc...

Also, groups are shown as distinguished name (with container etc), so very long. I only want the name.

I want to show it as follows:

> User1 - group1
>
> User1 - group2
>
> User2 - group1, etc

The code that shows the groups the users are member of, but not in the visual way i like is below:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\Input_CN.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    $User = Get-ADUser -filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -properties memberof 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SourceCN = $_.CN
        MemberOf = $User.MemberOf -join ";"
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
.\Output.csv
```

I have some other code that list the groups how I want, but I am unable to list it per user. And unable to combine it with the above code.

```
get-aduser -filter {cn -eq "Testuser"} -properties memberof |
Select -ExpandProperty memberof |
ForEach-Object{Get-ADGroup $_} |
Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine both code pieces like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\Input_CN.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties MemberOf, CN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach($group in $user.MemberOf) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            SourceCN = $user.CN
            MemberOf = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).Name
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Edit**

Although I have never seen an AD user to have no group membership at all (should have at least the default `Domain Users` in the MemberOf property), You commented that you would like to have a test for that aswell.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\Input_CN.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties MemberOf, CN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$user) {
        Write-Warning "No user found with CN '$($_.CN)'"
        # skip this one and resume with the next CN in the list
        continue
    }
    $groups = $user.MemberOf
    if (!$groups -or $groups.Count -eq 0) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                SourceCN = $user.CN
                MemberOf = 'No Groups'
            }
    }
    else {
        foreach($group in $groups) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                SourceCN = $user.CN
                MemberOf = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).Name
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\Output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This shows the groups as the SamAccountName, which is great. However, the groups are still on 1 line behind the user, seperated by ";".
User1 - group1;group2
user2 - group1;group2;group3 etc

Comment: @Maikel I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I have updated the code to export the desired format now.

Comment: Great, Thanks! Is it possible to also show the users who do not are member of groups? And show something as "No memberof group" for example?
I tried with something with `MemberOf = If((Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).Name){(Get-ADGroup -Identity $group).Name}Else{'**No Groups**'}`
This does not work, i guess because the user gets filtered out due to the foreach?

Comment: @Maikel AD users are always member of the default `Domain Users` group. When you create a user account in a domain, it is added to this group automatically. There is no such thing as a user not belonging to any group at all. See [Default Groups](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-security_groups.html). If you want to get users **not** member of a specific set of groups, than that's another question.

Comment: @Maikel It seems to me unlikely, but I have added new code to test if the MemberOf property of a user is totally empty.

Comment: i am working in an environment where removed users are not actually removed.
Therefor i have created a script to retrieve all the removed users, next step is to check which users have groups connected, en which users not.

Comment: Works like a charm... Thanks very much!

Comment: it seems that the script stops when the user is actually removed, so it does not skip and continue.
With a new list of users it works very good, but it would be nice if it skips users that do not longer exist

Comment: @Maikel I'm on mobile now.. You can add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the Get-AdUser cmd.

Comment: what actually helped was just to remove the "continue" in the first IF statement. Now it shows a blanco cell, and it continues with the rest. Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit clunky, but you can use nested loops:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\Input_CN.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -properties cn, memberof
        $user | ForEach-Object {
            $_.MemberOf |
                ForEach-Object {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        SourceCN = $user.CN
                        MemberOf = $_.split('[=,]')[1]
                }
        }
    }
} | Where-Object {$null -ne $_.MemberOf} | 
        Export-Csv -Path .\Output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

**UPDATE**: Updated to show only the 'CN' part of the group name and to filter any users who are not a member of any group.

Comment: This is almost what I need. It does show each group on a seperate row. But 2 small things i would like to have fixed:
1: If a user is not member of a group, the user is not shown. So it shows only users who are member of a group(s).

2: is it possible to only show the name/SamAccountname of the group?

Comment: @Maikel, I updated my example according to your comment.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me almost the result i like. See comment below with @Theo, which gives the same output as your code.
So I only need to show the users who do not have groups

Answer (score 0):

All in one line could be

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties Name, Created | Select-Object Name, Created, @{Name="Groups";Expression={Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName | Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -Eq 'Security'} | Join-String -Property Name -Separator ", "}}
```